# Rendering fields in ASP.NET Razor view with configurable order

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to allow customers to specify which fields will be drawn in which order, from among a fixed set of fields (address, home phone, SSN, first name, etc. etc.)

What is the best practice for this?  I feel like an HTML helper method like "DrawField" is appropriate, but can I use helpers like Html.EditorFor in the body of an HTML helper method?  When modelstate has errors and I redisplay the form, will the submitted values and errors be populated?

The "safest" approach seems to be an ugly big loop:

```
foreach( Field f in FieldList)
{
   if(f.Key == FieldKey.FirstName)
   {
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, StringResource("firstNameLabel"))
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
       <br />
   }

   if(f.Key == FieldKey.LastName)
   {
      ......
   }
}
```

There's gotta be a better way!

Answer (score 1):

Since the list of fields is fixed I would just order it in the controller and just have n regions in the view that will render the fields in the order they arrive in the model. I would structure the model so that it contains a list of the same object, but the content will be different for each one (First name, last name etc) .You can add whatever meta data you need to your model

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Items[0].Prop, StringResource(model.Items[0].PropName))
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Items[0].Prop)
```

......

That way you don't need any conditionals or loops. It's instead n generic regions driven by the data

Comment: good solution but as long as it not a strongly typed view and the object is of the same type like int or string

Comment: I guess the model could contain a list of objects that implement a common interface IProperty (IntProperty,StringProperty etc) with a Property of T called Prop.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried the common interface thing, and it turns out to be quite cumbersome. And unfortunately, some fields need to be drawn with checkboxes or radio buttons, others with multiple text fields, etc.  For the short term, I'm going with the big loop around a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tried you can try by creating a custom editor / display templates for the Model that takes care of ordering the fields.

To get a basic idea about model templates check this link http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

**UPDATE:**

I've tried a simple example. We have a `Person` model and I want to control the order in which the `FirstName` and `LastName` are displayed.

```
public class Person
{
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required")]
[Display(Name = "First Name:")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required")]
[Display(Name = "Last Name:")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Create a custom editor template `Person.cshtml` and place it in the `Views/Shared` folder. So whenever you call the `EditorFor` method for
`Person` this template will be used for rendering. For simplicity I'm passing the order in which they have to displayed as an array of fields through `ViewBag`.

```
@model RazorAndJson.Models.Person
@{
  var fields = ViewBag.FieldsOrder != null 
  ? ViewBag.FieldsOrder 
  : new[] { "FirstName", "LastName" };
}
@foreach(string field in fields)
{
    <p>
         @Html.Label(field)
         @Html.Editor(field)
         @Html.ValidationMessage(field)
    </p>
}
```

Comment: That looks like a good solution when all the fields want the same kind of editor, but I don't see how it can easily extend to textbox/textarea/dropdown/checkbox assortments.

Comment: You may have to try using the display meta data over properties to control the editor for fields